# How to express the volume of a sphere as iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am new to multivariable calculus. Is there a way to express the volume of a sphere with the equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$ as an **iterated integral** in the **cartesian coordinate system**, with each integral specifying the lower and upper limits for each respective variable $(x,y,z)$?
i.e. is there a way to express $$\int\int\int_{B}dv$$ where B denotes the set $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\}$
as some iterated integral
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{z_1}^{z_2}dzdydx$$ where $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2),(z_1,z_2)$ are the respective lower and upper limits for x,y,z for this integral?

In addition, this leads to my other question: suppose we only take the "upper back right" section of the sphere - that is, to take some subset $A\subset B$ where $$A:\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2,x>0,y>0,z>0\}$$this way $y=\sqrt{R^2-z^2-x^2}$ and $z=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ for all $(x,y,z)\in A$; since $y$ and $z$ can now both be expressed as a function of the other two variables for any points within the set, is there a way to calculate the volume integral
$$\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$? (I know for any triple integrals with variables $(x,y,z)$, if one variable can be expressed as function of the other two ($z=\phi(x,y)$)and another can be expressed as the function of the remaining one ($y=f(x)$), then one should first integrate $z$ then $y$ then $x$; but what about the case where two of the three variables can **both only** be expressed as a function of the other two variables? ($z=\phi(x,y)$ and $y=f(x,z)$)? Which should be integrated first or is it possible at all to evaluate this type of integral?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your second question, that integral that you wrote makes no sense. Note that $x$ can take any value from $0$ to $R$, that, for each such $x$, $y$ can take any value from $0$ to $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and that, for each such $x$ and each such $y$, $z$ can take any value from $0$ to $\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$. So, the integral should be$$\int_0^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$Concerning your first question, the answer is affirmative, but uninteresting. Since the volume of a cube whose side is $2R$ is $8R^3(=(2R)^3)$ and since the volume of a sphere with radius $R$ is $\frac43\pi R^3$, you can just take$$\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\frac\pi6\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$However, the natural way of doing it in Cartesian coordinates is$$\int_{-R}^R\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Thanks! A follow up question: when finding the integral of some set A where $A: \{ (x_1,x_2,...x_n): \phi (x_1,x_2,...x_n) = c \}$ , if $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ are all uniquely solvable, can we generalize a "formula" for finding the upper/lower limits for each of the n variables in iterated integral form?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.